# For each implementation in joins

Tags: join, mariadb

`deliveries` Table has `customer_id` and the `item_id` they want to buy. `items` table has items with `item_id` as primary as below

```
 deliveries                                 items
id  customer_id  item_id               item_id       item_name
1    10           100                     100        Delicious
2    10           111                     111        Super Delicious 
3    12           100
```

I want to see for every customer `(10, 12)` whether they bought the two items (`Delicious and Super Delicious`).

This I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM items LEFT JOIN deliveries ON items.item_id = deliveries.item_id
```

[image]

**Here specifically, I want to see customer with id `12` has not bought `item_id 111 as Null`, which would be 4th row in the result.**

Comment: What is the problem with what you have tried?

Comment: Here specifically, I want to see customer with id `12` has not bought `item_id 111 as Null`, which would be 4th row in the result. Updated the question thank you. But left join gives only 3 rows.

Comment: I see. I've added an example as an answer

Answer (score 1):

To get the full domain you need a cartesian product (cross join in sql lingo) between the two sets:

```
select distinct d.customer_id, i.item_id 
from deliveries d 
cross join items i;
```

from this set you can subtract the actual deliveries:

```
select distinct d.customer_id, i.item_id 
from deliveries d 
cross join items i 
where not exists (
    select 1 from deliveries d2 
    where i.item_id = d2.item_id 
    and d.customer_id = d2.customer_id
);
```

I'm not clear on how this null comes into play, but you can add a flag that says that this product has not been bought by this customer as:

```
select distinct d.customer_id, i.item_id, 'NOT BOUGHT' as status 
from deliveries d 
cross join items i 
where not exists (
    select 1 from deliveries d2 
    where i.item_id = d2.item_id 
    and d.customer_id = d2.customer_id
);
```

Finally, you can add the deliveries table to this set as:

```
select distinct d.customer_id, i.item_id, 'NOT BOUGHT' as status 
from deliveries d 
cross join items i 
where not exists (
    select 1 from deliveries d2 
    where i.item_id = d2.item_id 
    and d.customer_id = d2.customer_id
);
union all 
select d.customer_id, d.item_id, 'BOUGHT' as status 
from deliveries d;
```

Not sure if it answers your question, but I think it will give you a start.